# Is a facade repository an OK design?

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I need to design code for a complex multi-table update, ideally using a repository pattern to fit in with existing code structures.

Some of the tables which will be updated are specific to this flow, whereas others will be updated in future from other flows. e.g.

- Specific Tables A, B, C, D
- Address (common)
- Customer (common)

I am currently thinking of designing a "facade repository", which takes an address repository and customer repository, dependency injected, and updates all in one place.

Is this an OK approach, or a bit of an anti-pattern? I guess it's no longer a true repository, and while I'm not seeing any particular issues of going forward with this design, something doesn't quite feel right.

It will be using C# and EF, SQL backend.

Comment: Well if it look like a respository on the interface level, the fact that it map to more than one table in the implementation is not a problem,  we may need a bit more detail on what will look like the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an anti-pattern, and in fact is done all the time.  It's called a **Service Layer.**

Consider this diagram:

```
DB <---> Repository <---> Service Layer <---> Client
     ^       ^        ^                   ^
     SQL     EF      Objects             JSON
```

When discussing Fowler's patterns, its's helpful to have an actual copy of [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420).  It's especially useful if you intend to be "Fowler-compliant."

> #### Repository
>
> *Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.*

Repository exposes a simple interface, typically CRUD with perhaps some criteria capabilities like

```
criteria.Equals(Person.LastName, "Fowler");
```

The Service Layer, on the other hand, exposes business operations.

> #### Service Layer
>
> *Defines an application's boundary with a layer of services that establishes a set of available operations and coordinates the application's response in each operation.*

It is this Service Layer where your logic to take an address repository and customer repository, dependency inject it, and update all in one place will reside.

Naturally, if you just need some sort of helper class that wraps your functionality into one neat bundle, you can do that too.

**Further Reading**
[P of EAA: Repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)
[P of EAA: Service Layer](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)

Comment: Interesting ... I interpreted it a bit differently, obviously! But, a service layer could definitely be more appropriate if you're not calling CRUD methods on an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't *inherently* problematic.**

Or rather, I don't see it as a violation of the [repository pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). The point of the pattern is to *hide a potentially complex or unknown storage mechanism.* So, much to the contrary of it being an anti-pattern, the repository pattern is of *particular value* in precisely your situation — when a business object (or concept) doesn't map naturally or perfectly to a single table.

To put a name on it, I think you're dealing with what DDD would call an [Aggregate](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html).

> Aggregates are the basic element of transfer of data storage - **you
>   request to load or save whole aggregates.** Transactions should not
>   cross aggregate boundaries.

The emphasis is mine.

If you have a domain concept that covers or "aggregates" other business/domain objects, having a single invocation point for saves and so forth is **good**, because it can hide the gory details and create transactions as needed.

---

If your entity definitions *did* map to your tables naturally on a one-to-one basis, I might actually suggest the repository pattern is overkill. The [active record pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is usually simpler and less code to implement! And, if memory serves, Martin Fowler suggests in [his patterns book](https://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) that the Active Record pattern is a good choice for "simple" entity-schema maps. It's when you get complicated that you really start to need a more sophisticated abstraction, like a repository.

Comment: It's interesting that Fowler's book doesn't mention *Aggregate.*  For that, I guess you need [Eric Evans' book](https://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215).

Comment: Yeah. He probably doesn't in that book, b/c it's a DDD term ... not a "pattern." But, check the link. He's certainly aware of the concept and its value.